# VBScript takes significantly longer when run using Windows Scheduler

Tags: windows, vbscript, sas, scheduled-tasks

I have a VBScript (.vbs) file which runs a SAS project.  The program executes successfully when I run it manually by double-clicking the VBScript file and it takes about a minute and a half to finish.

However, when I schedule the VBScript file in the Windows Task Scheduler, it takes ridiculously long to run - the last time I tried I let it go for two hours before manually ending the task.  I know the task is starting because when I refresh the task in Task Scheduler it says it is currently running.

I have several other VBScripts that I use to schedule other SAS projects, none of which have given me this issue.  What gives?

Comment: First - you should put some debugging steps in there (maybe write .txt files out every so often) to see where the problem is.  Second - odds are something's different about running it interactively vs. running it in 'batch' mode.  Is there a prompt waiting for response?  Is there something that happens at logon that doesn't happen when it's run in batch?  Is there a rights issue, or a network drive connection not being restored?

Comment: Not the right place for this question, it [belongs here](http://serverfault.com/questions/151824/process-runs-slower-as-a-scheduled-task-than-it-does-interactively).

Comment: Scheduled processes run at a lower CPU and memory priority. http://serverfault.com/questions/151824/process-runs-slower-as-a-scheduled-task-than-it-does-interactively

Comment: It is possible that some windows response or interaction is gumming up the works. Always specify the CSCRIPT.EXE command line interpreter for a .VBS run from the Task Scheduler rather than WSCRIPT or nothing (defaulted to WSCRIPT). Remember to remove any windows environment calls like MsgBox, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this alias to force your script to execute with CSCRIPT interpreter. To debug timming, you can use the Timer() function, here is a example:

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Call ForceConsole()

tmpTimer = Timer()

For i = 0 to 10000
    a = a + 1
    b = Int(Rnd * 500)
    If b mod 2 = 0 Then b = 9
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine a
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine b
Next

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "This loop took " & (Timer()-tmpTimer) & " miliseconds"
WScript.StdIn.ReadLine

Function ForceConsole()
    If InStr(LCase(WScript.FullName), "cscript.exe") = 0 Then
        oWSH.Run "cscript " & Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34)
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Function
```